# What is the meaning of " we are the children of God "?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, words, names, theology

Shalom ,
What is the meaning when the jew say that and according to this can we say that Moses is the son of God as he is the biggest teacher " while not meaning what the Christians said " ?

I hope I did not get the information wrong .

The sentence " children(or sons) of God " is used in many places in the bible .
https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen+6%3A2&version=ESV

My question is can we say someone is the son of God as an honour to him for example Moses ?

EDIT : so accroding to a brother here "When using the phrase "children of Gcd", the Jews mean they are the Chosen People; with more responsibilities that other people, and hence a closer relationship with The Chooser than other people have."

The question :Is it possible to call someone the son of God if we knew that he was a great believer -because all jews are God Chosen can we call one specific by that- ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Could you [edit] your answer to add where you've heard people say this (or if you read it, where you read it)?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not 100% clear.

Nowhere is Moses referred to as the son of Gcd. Moses was a regular human being and his genealogy is clearly recorded ([Exodus 6:20](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%206%3A20&version=ESV) for example).

Your **single** reference is in the pre-flood area - about 2,000 years before Moses was born.

In Judaism that verse is translated  as "the children of the judges", as Elohim refers to judges, in other places. ([Rashi, Ramban and Midrash Rabba](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01424_part_1.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L2))

For example, [Exodus 22:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2022%3A28&version=ESV), is classically translated as "You shall not revile the judges, nor curse a ruler of your people."

When using the phrase "children of Gcd", the Jews mean they are the Chosen People; with more responsibilities that other people, and hence a closer relationship with The Chooser than other people have.

Comment: "When using the phrase "children of Gcd", the Jews mean they are the Chosen People; with more responsibilities that other people, and hence a closer relationship with The Chooser than other people have." 
Is it possible to call someone the son of God if we knew that he was a great believer ?